# Capture number of rows & other statistics after successful fread in data.table package

Tags: r, data.table

After a successful call to `fread`, if show progress is TRUE at least, the diagnostic `Read X rows and y (of z) columns from A GB file in HH:MM:SS` is shown. I have a function has multiple `fread` calls in a loop, and I would like to accumulate the number of rows, and possibly the time. Is that at all possible? Looking through the documentation, I do not see `fread` return anything other than the data table/frame.

Thank you.

#### Update - Sample similar code

```
Parse <- function(Years, Prefix, OutHeader){
  for (Year in Years) {
      [Snip unnecessary code]
      Filename <- SomeFunctionOf(Years)
      P <- fread(FileName, colClasses = ColClasses__P, header = TRUE, select = NeededColumns_P)
      Stats <- P[, .(A = sum(A, na.rm = TRUE), CurCount = .N,
                    B = sum(B), Z = sum(Z > 0, na.rm = TRUE)), by = G]
      setkey(Stats, G)
      write.csv(Stats, paste0(OutHeader, '_Identifier_', Year, '.csv'), row.names = FALSE)
      rm(P, Stats)
      gc()
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have this within a function you could just print the `dim` and time after each `fread`...

Comment: @drmariod I'm saving the processed results to different files, and am actually calling the data.table routines inside the call to write.table as the "x = A[i, j, by]", but you're right, I can separate it out and accumulate the dim if there is no inherent data.table answer. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't showing your code?

Comment: Sounds like a good feature request for a new function, `freadlist`. Even if you add up the dim, you won't have the memory size or time used there. I guess you mean like `raw_datasets = lapply(file_paths, fread)` or `lapply(file_paths, {... fread ...})` with other steps taken. I do this fairly frequently.

Comment: @cory Not sure it would help as there is nothing special about it, but let me sanitize it a bit and I'll post it for you.

Comment: @cory Sanitized code posted

Comment: what about `capture.output()` to get the printed message, then parsing that. Not sure there's much else you can do.

Comment: @Avraham : Thanks for posting this question. I have another problem regarding this. Sometimes I did not get this statement `Read X rows and y (of z) columns from A GB file in HH:MM:SS` at the end. Can anyone explain that?

Comment: @user2100721 It may depends on your ShowProgess. `showProgress=getOption("datatable.showProgress")` and if that is FALSE, I think you get nothing. Try explicitly passing `showProgress=TRUE`. PS, if you like the question, please upvote it 8-)

Comment: Wrap your `fread` calls (and potentially others) into some logging solution, my [logR](https://gitlab.com/jangorecki/logR) package tracks in/out rows but it requires postgres. You can very easily build own wrapper on `system.time()` and `dim()`.

Comment: As @drmariod suggested, I did that. I was wondering if `data.table` itself captured those values in a retrievable way or just reported them and flushed them. Thank you!

Comment: @drmariod, since I used your suggestion, please write it up as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks.